# Envio de e-mail autenticado com Swift Mailer

Tags: php, smtp, swiftmailer

Tenho um ficheiro php que envia e-mails autenticados utilizando a classe swift mailer.
Implementei a classe em um servidor mas o e-mail utilizado na autenticação é de outro servidor SMTP.
Inserimos tudo correctamente, a porta, a password, o servidor SMTP...
Porém a autenticação na hora de enviar o e-mai está a falhar.

Não é possível utilizar dados de outro servidor SMTP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deveria funcionar, mas não conheço essa classe para dar uma recomendação específica.

Recomendo antes a classe [MIME Email message](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/9-PHP-PHP-mailer-to-compose-and-send-MIME-messages.html) que serve para o mesmo propósito, e tem uma opção de debug que mostra o diálogo SMTP entre a classe e o servidor, para assim ficar sabendo exatamente que erro está sendo retornado de forma a poder resolver o problema.

Comment: obrigado pelo seu tempo, mas preciso da resposta mesmo para a classe Swift Mailer, a aplicação utiliza a classe.

Comment: Veja se tem uma opção de debug que faça mostrar o diálogo SMTP talvez em um log. Sem isso fica difícil diagnosticar o problema. Alternativamente, você pode tentar usar a classe mencionada acima com a opção de debug só para ver o que se passa a nível do SMTP.

Comment: Não consegui entender a origem do problema, mas valeu a sugestão para trocar de classe. Obrigado.